# Using aws-sdk javascript to get items from DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to follow this documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-examples.html

specifically the part to reading/writing to dynamodb. I was able to list the tables I have so the credentials are working, not sure if I have to provide them again.

this is the code:

```
var table = new AWS.DynamoDB({params: {TableName: 'MY_TABLE'}});
var key = 'UNIQUE_KEY_ID';

// Write the item to the table
var itemParams = {Item: {id: {S: key}, data: {S: 'data'}}};
table.putItem(itemParams, function() {
  // Read the item from the table
  table.getItem({Key: {id: {S: key}}}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data.Item); // print the item data
  });
});
```

1) So I first changed it to MyTableName
2) So MyTableName has just a Hash Key which is type String, so I set var key to 'testingkey1'

3) I didn't change the data, I'm fine with it being the string 'data' for now
4) I added a `document.write(data.Item)` below `console.log(data.Item);`

So of course I don't see that item being added to MyTableName on the dynamodb console. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the new DynamoDB-doc javascript [SDK](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-document-js-sdk) which makes the work with DynamoDB much easier - like working with JavaScript objects.

Comment: ahh okay, i will take a look! do you by any chance know what might be causing the error above? thanks!